# RCCR oscillator tuned with a single pot

Tags: transistors, oscillator

I have incomplete details of a very interesting RCCR oscillator circuit that, back in 1960, used just 3 transistors as the amplifier. In those days, the transistors were germanium PNP, almost certainly. I cannot see how just 3 transistors can do that, because the circuit requires to be driven in push-pull with some gain on the in-phase (push) side. I need suggestions how to do that, using Si transistors, of course.
The frequency range I need is 20 kHz to 60 kHz. In this range, ordinary op-amps can introduce unwanted phase-shifts unless the closed-loop gain is kept very low.

I am including the original article and the results of a Spice simulation.
[Original article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeDO0.jpg)
[image: Spice simulation]

Comment: expand your zip locally, then attach any picture files, or if necessary screenshots of your display

Comment: John Woodgate - Hi, (a) As just commented, please [edit] your question & upload relevant image files (use Ctrl+G in the edit box, on a PC). If you reach the limit (2 files?) for a new user, then put them on a public share somewhere and some kind person will edit them into your question for you. (b) Please also add a clear question. Are you trying to understand how the circuit works? Or are you trying to build it (without germanium transistors?) and have a problem doing that? Please try to be as specific as possible about the question, and include any relevant context & constraints. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Neil, but I don't know how to atatch, as i said.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I can reduce to 2 files and do as you say. I thought my message was clear: I don't see how to make a 3-transistor amplifier that will  produce 2 anti-phase outputs, the in-phase one being a little larger. I will use Si transistors, of course. When I see a circuit that does that, I will build it.